# Unable to get exact data from XML into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am just trying to alert the email from the XML but I am getting this as an alert.

> ▛▛email1@mail.com ▛

Help me in removing these box symbols. I actually wanted to validate the email, but I couldn't do that because the value returned contains these symbols.

JavaScript:

```
function process(){     
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 || xmlhttp.readyState == 0){
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "../text/info.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = responseServer;
        xmlhttp.send();
    } else {
        setTimeout("process()", 1500);
    }
}

function responseServer(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        docxml = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        emails = docxml.getElementsByTagName('email');
        alert(emails[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your xml?

Comment: <emails>
    <email>email1@mail.com</email>
</emails>

Comment: why not `emails[0].textContent`?

Comment: @gurvinder372, Do you mean `emails[0].firstChild.textContent` ?

Comment: Try either of them and tell me the output

Comment: hopefully, the emails[0].firstChild.textContent worked..!! thank you.! i never used textContent before.. i always use nodeValue to print the xml element values on to the web site..!! 

thank you for your instant reply :)

Comment: either of them will work, as i mentioned only one element in the xml.!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
alert( emails[0].firstChild.nodeValue );
```

with

```
alert( emails[0].firstChild.textContent );
```